# When building a tree using ng-include, my 'ng-click' is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a tree using the following code with 'ng-include', and it's looking fine:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_node.html">
    <a ng-click="select(this, data, $event)">{{data.name}}</a>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.children track by $index" ng-include="'tree_node.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in venueTree track by $index" ng-include="'tree_node.html'"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that when clicking on the {{data.name}}, the 'select' function isn't called in my controller.  I have no javascript errors, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

reapter creating new scopes to you can access parent scope using $parent or ng-init like ie: 
please see here: http://jsbin.com/xowub/3/edit

html:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in venueTree track by $index" ng-include="'tree_node.html'" ng-init="parent=this"></li>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_node.html">
    <a ng-click="parent.select(this, data, $event)">{{data.name}}</a>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.children track by $index" ng-include="'tree_node.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. The ng-click seems to work just fine in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Yry0YSidiXfgasHQlHO?p=preview) I made.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.venueTree = [{children:[{name:'one'},{name:'dos'}]},{children:[{name:'drei'},{name:'fyra'}]}];
  $scope.select = function(a,b,c){alert(b.name); console.log({a:a, b:b, c:c})};
});
```